# Phases/Plugins and Maven Project Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

When i save changes in my java source code with Eclipse i notice in the Progress tab

[image]

As i am using Maven which phase or plugin (goal) is being invoked here ?

What happens behind the scene ?

Comment: I have deleted my answer (simple copy of the documentation), and look forward reading [howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger)'s.

Comment: Put simply, the _Maven Project Builder_ does what is necessary to allow the incremental Eclipse compiler to be used when a changed Java file is saved, so that the application can be run/debugged any time without further build steps. It depends on what is in the POM file, what changes have been made (the idea of a project builder is to build the project incrementally), and how Maven and m2e have been configured. More precise, [this method](https://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/builder/MavenBuilder.java#n192) is executed.

Comment: @howlger Don't be shy, you can put it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

simply it updates maven dependencies based on your pom.xml or resolves Maven dependencies from the Eclipse workspace without installing to the local Maven repository.
visit this site to know about that in detail https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Any change to the source code or pom file of the project signal eclipse to rebuild (if build automatically is enabled). However, maven builds, would check for the required artefacts from the remote repository and download them to local repository (under .maven dir) before running compile phase. Maven plugin can be configured to run offline in which when remote repository will not be queried - making the build execute faster.